# android and power point

Tags: android

I want to play power point presenetaions on android.
basically when user cliks on button , play ppt file. How to do that? any example?

Comment: How's this programming related?  Maybe should be moved to SuperUser?

Comment: I think you want an app.

Comment: You have to write a ppt viewer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google shows an open source project that you could use to learn how to do what you need ([link](http://kenai.com/projects/pptandroid)). Or perhaps you can install another application and fire off an intent to it to open your ppt file.