# How to embed a power point slide in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a powerpoint slide show of just one page, when a user of android press a button i want to run that slide show, and after the slide show is finished it will be back in the previous place, how can i do it in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android and power point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646977/android-and-power-point)

Comment: To me, it would seem like a huge waste of resources (not to mention problems with compatibility) to start powerpoint for just one slide. Couldn't you show that as an image inside your app, or a new screen?

Comment: But I have an Animation in it